# Parsing HTTP Request to url ending with .json

Tags: java, http, jax-ws, swagger

When I make an HTTP request to an URL of the form `"host:port/x/swagger.json"` the `.json` is removed by the `javax.ws.rs` annotations.

Does this have to do with the Path annotation regex, or some type of configuration I have to do?

Comment: What is "`host:port/x/swagger.json`"? What do you get when you type that in your browser? Where is the code that produces the behaviour you describe?

Answer (score -1):

In URL, you should use %2E instead of [.].
For other encoding character, please refer [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: @cricket_007 it depend on which tool/library you used for input. Anyway i propose the idea worth to try, not something you have to use in every cases.

Comment: It's a static file located under that path, it shouldn't need encoded.

Comment: As i said, it depend on which library/tool that you use. In this case (javax.ws.rs annotations), i think the encoding is needed. [See more here](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html/_Encoded_and_encoding.html)